# MacBook Pro runs out of battery and feels warm when left unplugged and in sleep mode overnight

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I have tried turning off Screen Time and it still drains all the way to 0%. Leaving it plugged in is not a solution -- That will still result in my computer consuming energy all night.

I want to get to the root of the problem and figure out what is consuming so much energy.

Should I be quitting all my apps before going into sleep mode? I thought the point of sleep mode is that it pauses all processes running. Or should I just be shutting off my computer instead of leaving it in sleep mode?

Comment: Which model of MacBook Pro (year, etc)? What OS version are you on? Are you closing the lid? Do you have any peripherals attached? Until you figure out the cause, I would still plug in overnight, as running the battery down to 0% every night is not good for it. Screen Time is just monitoring how long you use the Mac -- why do you think that might have been responsible? Normally, you shouldn't need to quit apps, nor shutdown at night. I would use Activity Monitor to see if that reveals what is using lots of Energy.

Answer (score 0):

Apple lets you tell precisely which apps use energy and battery hour by hour. We can guess what you should do, but why not determine exactly what’s happening on your Mac so you know how you want to shut it down or endsure the sleep energy usage is how you prefer?

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-battery-settings-mchlfc3b7879/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-sleeps-or-wakes-unexpectedly-mchlp2995/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/view-energy-consumption-actmntr43697/mac

The last two you will use often as apps change how they work. The first is set it and forget it most of the time until you learn more about what’s taking the charge out of the battery overnight.